# Bash script upd error

Tags: bash

I execute my bash script PLCCheck as process

```
./PLCCheck &
```

**PLCCheck**

```
while read -r line 
do 
    ... 
    def_host=192.168.100.110
    def_port=6002
    HOST=${2:-$def_host}
    PORT=${3:-$def_port}

    echo -n "OKConnection" | netcat -u -c $HOST $PORT 
done < <(netcat -u -l -p 6001)
```

It listens on UDP Port 6001.

When I want to execute my second bash script SQLCheck as process that listens on UDP Port 4001

```
./SQLCheck &
```

**SQLCheck**

```
while read -r line 
do 
   ... 
   def_host=192.168.100.110 
   def_port=6002
   HOST=${2:-$def_host}
   PORT=${3:-$def_port} 

   echo -n "OPENEF1" | netcat -u -c $HOST $PORT 
done < <(nc -l -p 4001)
```

I got this error:

```
Error: Couldn't setup listening socket (err=-3)
```

Port 6001 and 4001 are open in the iptables and both scripts work as a single process. Why do I get this error?

Comment: Hmmm... Both uses default port 6002 but I cannot see how the `PORT` is used in the `PCLCheck` script. Maybe they collide...

Comment: Sorry. The same way `netcat -u -c $HOST $PORT`. PLCCheck sends every 5 Minutes. SQLCheck sends randomly every 120 - 300 minutes.

Comment: Try to use `set -x` at the beginning of both scripts and launch them as a foreground process in two terminals to find out in which line this error message appears. Based on your partial script it can be in any line...

Comment: I got it. The barcode reader has an issue. So I couldn't listen on Port 4001. Thank you guys!

Comment: Hmmm... Then how can the script work alone as you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the man page of `nc`. I think it is used on a wrong way:

```
 -l      Used to specify that nc should listen for an incoming connection rather
         than initiate a connection to a remote host.  It is an error to use this
         option in conjunction with the -p, -s, or -z options.  Additionally,
         any timeouts specified with the -w option are ignored.
```

...

```
 -p source_port
         Specifies the source port nc should use, subject to privilege restrictions
         and availability.  It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the
         -l option.
```

According to this one should not use `-l` option with `-p` option!

Try to use without `-p`, just `nc -l 4001`. Maybe this is the error...

Comment: @Philipp88: `-l` is needed, the `-p` is not needed.

Comment: @Philipp88: Hmm. It is difficult to guess based on your partial scriptlets, but using these options together is definitely an error .

Comment: @Philipp88: I browsed a little bit, and this seems to be an error only according to the (RedHat) Linux man page. If You use different nc distribution, this can be normal.